# Sdk Frozen Bundles

Tags: sdk, bundles

can you help me with this query regarding bundles, the previous version of our app has a frozen bundle, so that the current version does not download it.
This is ok for the current version, since it contains the strings of this bundle locally.
After the translators work - we want to update the strings in the application, to do this we build a bundle that contains only the strings that have changed since the release.
We set this new bundle as a production. Everything works fine for the current version of the application. But the previous version remains unchanged.
Any suggestions to solve this problem? Other than updating the entire frozen bundle every time.

How to support older versions that are tied to frozen bundles? They won't be able to update strings for older versions?

Expecting some help and guidance